# I/O passthrough on Xilinx CPLD

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I'm trying to implement a signal passtrough on xc2c64a cpld, as if the wires were connected directly.

```
port (
 OUTPUT : out STD_LOGIC;
 INPUT : in STD_LOGIC;
);

--INPUT and OUTPUT are defined as IOSTANDARD on the same bank in the constraint file

[Some code]
...
[/Some code]

if (condition) then
  OUTPUT<=INPUT;
end if;
```

The code works, on OUTPUT i have the same logical level of INPUT.
But there's a problem. It doesn't act as if they were two wires connected directly: there's a (approximately) 16KOhm resistor between them.
Is it avoidable? Can cplds work this way?

Comment: Do you know how a CPLD works? It's not a relais that connects inputs with outputs. It's a big piece of CMOS logic. There is no direct electrical connection between inputs and outputs, just the logical value is transfered.

Comment: If resistance is a problem you should look into having your CPLD driving a relay.

Comment: May I ask what you intend to do? As @Paebbels points out, a CPLD is a huge piece of logic.